# libreoffice calc - vary column in indirect

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, libreoffice, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

Assume sheets that have some values on columns `B-K`.

Each sheet has

```
R2=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("b"&$O$2):INDIRECT("b"&$O$3))
R3=STDEV(INDIRECT("b"&$O$2):INDIRECT("b"&$O$3))
```

for, say,

```
O2=1436
O3=10260
```

How can I write the indirect s.t. I can drag it right to sumarise the other columns?

i.e.

```
S2=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("c"&$O$2):INDIRECT("c"&$O$3))
S3=STDEV(INDIRECT("c"&$O$2):INDIRECT("c"&$O$3))
T2=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("d"&$O$2):INDIRECT("d"&$O$3))
T3=STDEV(INDIRECT("d"&$O$2):INDIRECT("d"&$O$3))
```

Comment: Instead of `INDIRECT("c"&$O$2):INDIRECT("c"&$O$3)` try using index `INDEX(C:C,$O$2):INDEX(C:C,$O$3)`  It would work for Excel but I do not have libreoffice to test.

Comment: @ScottCraner Works perfectly, thank you! Want to make an answer out of it?